# Date criteria in MS Access 365 failing

Tags: sql, oracle, date, ms-access

I just upgraded to Office 365 and am having trouble with some very basic Access queries.

I have a local db that connects to a remote Oracle db via ODBC.  The connection is working fine; I can open the tables and view data, or run a select query.  But I have an update query that relies on date criteria that is failing with error:

> [Oracle][ODBC] Syntax Error or access violation (#0)

```
UPDATE localtable 
INNER JOIN remotetable AS remotetable_DSN 
ON localtable.[Cust ID] = remotetable.[Cust ID] 
SET localtable.[Status] = "Valid"
WHERE remotetable.status ="Valid" 
AND remotetable.end_date =#12/31/9999# <-- if I remove this line, it runs fine
```

My coworker has similar queries that are working properly on Access 365.  His queries behave the same way on my PC: date criteria cause the query to fail, removing the date allows the query to run.

I'm thinking that I must have some setting that's causing this, but I don't know what it could be.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a `Date` issue.

if you define a table alias `remotetable AS remotetable_DSN`, you must use it. or simply remove the `AS remotetable_DSN` part and your code should work.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  This query was created in Query Designer and somehow got muddled when I looked at in SQL view.  The actual query:
```UPDATE localtable 
INNER JOIN remotetable
ON localtable.[Cust_ID] = remotetable.Cust_ID
 SET localtable.[Status] = "Valid"
WHERE remotetable.Status="Valid" 
AND remotetable.end_dt=#12/31/9999#```

It's been working perfectly for two years, and continues to work if I remove the date criteria.

Comment: Nope, that's not it either.  This code runs perfectly on a colleague's computer using the same versions and the same ODBC drivers.  His queries fail on my machine, so I'm pretty sure it's something specific to my setup but I don't know what it is.